# Writing to external SD card in KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

So is there no way for me to move a file from internal memory to the external SD card in Android KitKat version? I used to use Wifi Transfer style apps to move stuff from my laptop to the internal memory, and then move them to the SD Card using one of the many explorer apps for Android. Is this not possible at all anymore??

Seems like an uncalled for restriction!

Comment: Well known issue. Please see: [Workaround for Android 4.4 not being able to write to SD cards?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/64381/16575)

Comment: Is there actually a question here, or is this just a rant?

Comment: There was a question - "Is this not possible at all anymore?". But yes, I did feel like ranting :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kitkat introduced quite a few security "enhancements" over previous releases. Many of them being local restrictions on what apps can and cannot access. Though it is was with good intentions, there is the issue of convenience.
Luckily though, it isn't a complete lock out. Apps now have to request an "access external media" permission (the list of things most people don't read when installing apps). Sadly, not all app developers have updated their software with this new permission for KitKat compatibility. So that is where you should be aiming your frustrations at.
If you have a rooted device, use a root privileged file manager, or if not, contact the developers of the apps that don't work, and request that they update them to be KitKat compatible. 
I hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks! You should add your answer to the question others have linked here as duplicate.

Comment: Okay, having read that other answer and a bit more about permissions - my understanding is that the new WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE only allows apps restrictive write permissions - they can only write to their own folders on the external SD card, and those will be deleted when the app is uninstalled. So does this mean there will be no more file manager apps that can move files to different dirs on the card?